# Add a footnote to the bottom of a tab_model table in sjPlot (R)

Tags: r, sjplot

Very straightforward question, but how can one add a footnote to the bottom of a table displaying two regression models next to each other? I have created two similar OLS regressions with `lm` and displayed their coefficients next to each other using the `tab_model` function in R. Everything works perfectly, but I now need to add a footnote to the bottom of the table. Is there a way to do this? Perhaps using the `CSS` argument?

Sample Code: (Dataframes are generic, as the question of a footnote would apply to any displayed regressions)

```r
reg_1 <- lm(Outcome ~ V1 + V2 + V3 + V4, data = df_1)
reg_2 <- lm(Outcome ~ V1 + V2 + V3 + V4, data = df_2)

tableA <- tab_model(reg_1, reg_2, auto.label = TRUE, show.se = TRUE, show.ci = FALSE, p.style = "scientific_stars", dv.labels = c("Model1","Model2"), pred.labels = c("Intercept","V1", "V2", "V3", "V4"), title = "Table A", digits = 3)
```